# How to directly go to the non-first scene of the sibling scene in React Native with react-native-router-flux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-native-router-flux

In the following code snippet, how to directly go to `completeInfo` from `login` without executing the `home`?

Thanks.

```
<Scene key="root">
    <Scene key="loginScene">
        <Scene key="login" component={Login} initial={true}/>
        <Scene key="register" component={Register}/>
    </Scene>
    <Scene key="homeScene">
        <Scene key="home" component={Home}/>
        <Scene key="completeInfo" component={CompleteInfo}/>
    </Scene>
</Scene>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `clone={true}` prop to completeInfo scene, then you can directly push it.

Comment: Thank You, it worked. 
Scenes marked with clone will be treated as templates and cloned into the current scene's parent when pushed. If current scene is `home`, then `Actions.completeInfo()`, will clone new `completeInfo` scene?  and `homeScene` will contain 3 scenes?

Comment: I have no idea, but if it was the case, I think debugger would throw a warning about duplicate keys (if they do not mutate keys on cloned scenes). @liupeixin

In their example they do it the same way:
https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/Example/Example.js